# How can one switch between symmetry modes in space plane hangar?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I don't know what I did, normally the Space Plane Hangar (SPH) uses mirror symmetry - meaning if you place two horizontal stabilizers they will both be on the top of the vessel. And the Vehicle Assembly Building (VAB) uses radial symmetry - meaning the horizontal stabilizers will be on opposite sites of the vessel.

I've done something and now some parts in the SPH are using radial symmetry.

[image: Radial attachment isn't what i want]

How do you switch symmetry modes? I know "X" will change the number of symmetry points you have, but what changes symmetry mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "R" key will change your attachment symetry between radial and mirror.

[image: Radial is good]

Comment: Wow. I honestly didn't know that! The more you know. xD

Comment: @FinnRayment: I'm pretty sure that was just introduced in the Beta.  Makes building booster assisted space planes in the VAB significantly easier.

Comment: @MBraedley Ohh yeah. I just did some this morning with it. **So** useful.